# Angular material and bootstrap

Tags: angular

I am so new in Angular and trying to create a simple application. From some of the videos which I watched I have noticed Angular Material can be used for styling. could you please help me to find the main difference between angular material and bootstrap? and advantages which might be useful to choose in early steps of creating an application?

Comment: I would recommend Material. Bootstrap may be simpler than Material, but the latter contains components that can be directly used in the application and follows material design style which gives a live feeling. Since your application is simple, you can implement it easily.

Answer (score 0):

"Responsiveness" is the primary reason why developers consider Bootstrap over the competitors, whereas "Ui components" was stated as the key factor in picking Material Design for Angular. Bootstrap and Material Design for Angular are both open source tools, I would recommend both